# Is apache-storm-2.x.x is released?

Tags: version, apache-storm

I currently work on a project which requires apache-storm as the streaming processor. Now I have worked with apache-storm 0.10.1, 0.9.4 and 1.0.2 versions. What I need to know is whether the 2.x.x version of apache-storm is released (at least the SNAPSHOT version).

Also I would like to know the comparison between 1.x.x vs 2.x.x of apache-storm versions.

I tried searching but did not find much about above topics. Any information is much appreciated. Thank you in advance. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the time of this writing, Apache Storm 2.0 has not been released. Only official Storm releases are available for download on storm.apace.org. If it's not there is hasn't been officially released.

The major difference between what we are currently calling 2.0 and earlier versions is the migration of the cloture code to Java. There will be other improvements, new features, and fixes as well.

If you are interested in following the development of Apache Storm you should read or subscribe to the dev@storm.apache.org mailing list.

Comment: Thanks Taylor :) I have already subscribed to dev@storm.apache.org mailing list. 
I think by "cloture", you meant "Clojure" right?
Can we still build the code in github and use it?

Comment: I can see on the github release page https://github.com/apache/storm/releases 2.0.0 version is available for download.
But do not see any announcement or download link http://storm.apache.org/downloads.html for 2.0.0 release.

Answer (score 2):

Only Snapshot version is released.